# Why isn't the count variable in my table function being incremented?

Tags: c

I'm doing a project for class where I make an ordered linked list of structs containing two random 1-6 rolls and their total. I'm trying to create a table of two columns. The left column will be the numbers 1-13(all the possible totals plus the two impossible values of 1 and 13) and the right column will be the number of occurences for each possible total.

Here is a function I wrote to perfom this task.

```
void table(struct node * roll_list){
    int i;
    int count;
    int total;

    for(i = 1; i < 14; i++){
        count = 0;
        while(roll_list){
            total=roll_list->total;
            if(i==total){
                count++;
                roll_list = roll_list->next;
            }else{
                roll_list = roll_list->next;
            }
    }
    printf("%d : %d\n",i,count);
    }
}
```

The function contains a for loop that executes 13 times. For each `i` value a variable `count` is set to 0 and a `while` loop is executed that runs through the list. Inside a `while` loop is an `if else` statement. If `i` is equal to the current nodes total, the `count` variable is incremented and we move to the next node. Else we move to the next node without incrementing the `i` variable.

After the `while` loop is finished a print statement prints the row for each of the two columns. The `for` loop then starts over for the next `i` value etc.

The problem I'm having is the output for the number of occurrences column is always zero, which suggests the count variable isn't being incremented.

I have another function which prints a table which is slightly different and that works fine.

```
void print_list(struct node * roll_list){
    while(roll_list){
        printf("Roll one: Dice01: %d,  Dice02: %d,  Total: %d\n", roll_list->dice01, roll_list->dice02, roll_list->total );
        roll_list = roll_list->next;
    }
}
```

So the values are all there in the list and everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You failed to initialize `roll_list` for each loop.

You should use another variable to iterate in the loop.

```
void table(struct node * roll_list){
    struct node * roll;
    int i;
    int count;
    int total;
    for(i = 1; i < 14; i++){
        count = 0;
        roll = roll_list;
        while(roll){
            total=roll->total;
            if(i==total){
                count++;
                roll = roll->next;
            }else{
                roll = roll->next;
            }
        }
        printf("%d : %d\n",i,count);
    }
}
```

Alternative way: if the maximum number is fixed, why not calculate all `count` in one loop?

```
void table(struct node * roll_list){
    int i;
    int count[14] = {0}; /* initialize all elements to zero */
    int total;
    while(roll_list){
        total=roll_list->total;
        if(1 <= total && total < 14){
            count[total]++;
        }
        roll_list = roll_list->next;
    }
    for (i = 1; i < 14; i++){
        printf("%d : %d\n",i,count[i]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to point your roll_list to the head pointer again ;

```
void table(struct node * roll_list){
int i;
int count;
int total;
struct node *head = roll_list;
for(i = 1; i < 14; i++){
    count = 0;
    roll_list = head;
    while(roll_list){
        total=roll_list->total;
        if(i==total){
            count++;
            roll_list = roll_list->next;
        }else{
            roll_list = roll_list->next;
        }
}
printf("%d : %d\n",i,count);
}
}
```